# Projection matrix can only map onto its column space

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

There are two questions on my homework. I think the answers for them are trivially NO. Since for (a), if $P$ is a projection onto $S_1$, then $S_1=S=$ the column space of $P$. The same argument follows for (b) lead to another NO.

The reason for both of the NO here is the word "onto".

So did I missed something here?

Thanks!